# ASP.net commandname won't fire

Tags: asp.net, events, button, command, arguments

I am having trouble when trying to fire a button in a GridView with the parameter CommandName = "x", I try to reach my "If" in the GridView1_RowCommand event but I just cant for some reason, if you could help me I'd be gratefull .

This is my .aspx part

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
 <ContentTemplate>
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" CellPadding="4" 
            EnableModelValidation="True" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" 
            Height="193px" Width="968px" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" 
            AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="ID" 
            DataSourceID="SOURCE1" onrowcommand="GridView1_RowCommand">
            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
            <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Button Text = "Seleccionar" runat="server" CommandName="X" CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>' />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" InsertVisible="False" 
                    ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="ID" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="IDEmpresa" HeaderText="IDEmpresa" 
                    SortExpression="IDEmpresa" />
            </Columns>
            <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
        </asp:GridView> 
   </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

And this is my C#  code:

```
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "X")
    {
        int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
        GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[index];
        Label1.Text = "WOW It reached out";
    }
}
```

I followed the instructions of the ASP.net page, and im fairly new to .net (I dont know if the UpdatePanel has something to do with it)

Comment: did you disable the view state ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing a quick test, the code you have provided works, but I did have to wire up my own datasource.

What you are missing here is that Label1 is outside of your UpdatePanel and will not refresh based on your localized postback within the UpdatePanel.

A word of caution with GridViews and UpdatePanels/Buttons.  Make sure you are not manually binding/rebinding during Page_Load, and if you have code to do so, you do so within an `if(!IsPostBack) { }` statement.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the advice, I dont know why but in my original code, I had a variable in the RowCommand "int ID" or something, that used to be printed on a external label (with proper .ToString();) everytime the UpdatePanel made his own postback, booted up the PC again and it worked for some mystical reason...